# trying to make my own token . But i am getting an error while compiling

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp

pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

/* My ethereum token */

abstract contract ERC20Token {
function name() virtual public view returns (string memory);
function symbol() virtual public view returns (string memory);
function decimals() virtual public view returns (uint8);
function totalSupply() virtual public view returns (uint256);
function balanceOf(address _owner) virtual public view returns (uint256 balance);
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) virtual public returns (bool success);
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) virtual public returns (bool success);
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) virtual public returns (bool success);
function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) virtual public view returns (uint256 remaining);

```
event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
```

}

contract Owned {
address public owner;
address public newOwner;

```
event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed _from, address indexed _to);

constructor() {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function transferOwnership(address _to) public {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    newOwner = _to;
}

function acceptOwnership() public {
    require(msg.sender == newOwner);
    emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
    owner = newOwner;
    newOwner = address(0);
}
```

}

contract Token is ERC20Token, Owned {

```
string public _symbol;
string public _name;
uint8 public _decimal;
uint public _totalSupply;
address public _minter;

mapping(address => uint) balances;

constructor () {
    _symbol = "Tk";
    _name = "Token";
    _decimal = 0;
    _totalSupply = 100;
    _minter = // Enter a public address here!

    balances[_minter] = _totalSupply;
    emit Transfer(address(0), _minter, _totalSupply);
}

function name() public override view returns (string memory) {
    return _name;
}

function symbol() public override view returns (string memory) {
    return _symbol;
}

function decimals() public override view returns (uint8) {
    return _decimal;
}

function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {
    return _totalSupply;
}

function balanceOf(address _owner) public override view returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
}

function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public override returns (bool success) {
    require(balances[_from] >= _value);
    balances[_from] -= _value; // balances[_from] = balances[_from] - _value
    balances[_to] += _value;
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public override returns (bool success) {
    return transferFrom(msg.sender, _to, _value);
}

function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public override returns (bool success) {
    return true;
}

function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public override view returns (uint256 remaining) {
    return 0;
}

function mint(uint amount) public returns (bool) {
    require(msg.sender == _minter);
    balances[_minter] += amount;
    _totalSupply += amount;
    return true;
}

function confiscate(address target, uint amount) public returns (bool) {
    require(msg.sender == _minter);

    if (balances[target] >= amount) {
        balances[target] -= amount;
        _totalSupply -= amount;
    } else {
        _totalSupply -= balances[target];
        balances[target] = 0;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type address

Comment: what are those "ERC20Token, Owned" and which solidity compiler version are you using?

Comment: owned is the name of other contract and the solidity version is 0.8.6

Comment: the error is probably in ERC20Token Contract or Owned Contract

Comment: @MajdTL Can you edit your code and put the whole contract?

Comment: @IsmailElMoudni it is not my code

Answer (score 2):

So there seem to be a couple of problems with your code.

First of all, you pass `0` into `Transfer()` as an address but an address needs to be a 20 byte value in the form of `0x.....` see [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/types.html?highlight=address#address).

Secondly, as already pointed out in the comments, you are possibly missing the [import statements](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/layout-of-source-files.html#importing-other-source-files) for the contracts you want to inherit from (`contract Token is ERC20Token, Owned {...`).

Thirdly, you are missing the last curly bracket `}`.

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do with your code so maybe you have to be more precise with your question and the information you posted. However, I made you some sample code that works (and hopefully does what you aim for), to play around with

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.11;

import {ERC20} from "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Token is ERC20 {
  address owner;

  constructor () ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") {
    owner = msg.sender;
    _mint(msg.sender, 1000 * 10 ** 18);
  }

  function mint(address to, uint amount) external {
    require(msg.sender == owner, "Function must be called by the contract owner!");
    _mint(to, amount);
  }  
}
```

Here is a tutorial that explains how to deploy your own ERC20 token:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZLFiGHIxS1c